# javascript tofixed decimal places doesn't work

Tags: javascript

What's the error in my script? 
It must have something do to with tofixed, not sure if it's the right place where it should be?

The rounding seems like to not work. Still having endless decimal places.

```js
function output() {
  var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
  var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = (parseFloat(value1) + parseFloat(value2)) / parseFloat(value3).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> / </span>
<input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"> </p>
```

Comment: What's the error you are having? Being more specific will help you get better answers.

Comment: edited my posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `toFixed` on the result of `parseFloat(value3)`, and then using that as the right-hand operand of `*` — turning it back into a number again. Then you're taking the number resulting from the multiplication and assigning it to `innerHTML`, which turns it into a string using the default `toString`.

You probably meant to apply `toFixed(2)` to the overall result:

```
document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = ((parseFloat(value1) + parseFloat(value2)) * parseFloat(value3)).toFixed(2);
// --------------------------------------------^--------------------------------------------------------------^
```

```js
function output() {
  var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
  var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
  var value3 = document.getElementById('value3').value;
  document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = ((parseFloat(value1) + parseFloat(value2)) / parseFloat(value3)).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<span> / </span>
<input id="value3" type="text" onchange="output();" />
<p id="result1"> </p>
```